# Using a local img in flatlist (React-Native)

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

My problem is probably very basic, but im new to programming.
Basically I want to see a flatlist with for each category the title and the img

This is my category constructor:

```
    class Category{
    constructor(id, title, catImg){
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.catImg = catImg;
    }
}
```

these are my 3 categories:

```
     export const CATEGORIES = [
    new Category('c1', 'Studeren', require('../assets/studeren.png')),
    new Category('c2', 'Wonen', require('../assets/wonen.png')),
    new Category('c3', 'EersteVoertuig', require('../assets/voertuig.png'))
  ];
```

this is where I want to call the elements:

```
    const CategoryGridTile = props  => {
    return(
        <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.gridItem} onPress = {props.onSelect}>
            <View >
                <Text>{props.title}</Text>
            </View>
            <Image source ={props.catImg} style={‌{width: 150, height: 150}}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>

    );
};
```

It does work for the `props.title` part, but it doesnt for the `props.catImg` part
(Meaning I can see the title, but no image. I have tried to directly put the img path instead of props.catImg, and that works, but thats not how I want to do it)

EDIT: I figured this code is also needed to understand my mistake?

```
const CategoryScreen = props => {
    const renderGridItem = (itemData) => {
        return <CategotyGridTile
        title ={itemData.item.title}
        onSelect={() =>{            
            props.navigation.navigate({
                routeName: 'CategorieVragen',
                params: {
                    categoryId: itemData.item.id
            }});
        }}/>;
    };
    return(
        <FlatList
        data={CATEGORIES}
        renderItem ={renderGridItem}
        numColums = {2}
        />
        )
}
```

Comment: I actually just manage to do it. Do I delete this question now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to send CATEGORIES as props to CategotyGridTile

in CategoryScreen

```
return <CategotyGridTile 
    categories={CATEGORIES}
    {...props}
   />
```

in CategoryGridTile

```
<Image source ={props.categories.catImg} style={‌{width: 150, height: 150}}/>
```